# Elasticsearch:kibana dashboard

Tags: excel, elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard

How to connect excel file and kibana dashboard if excel file is updated then dashboard direct updated list for me all process

I want to connect excel file the kibana and when I change excel file data than the kibana dashboard is updated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the data using Kibana, you need to load such data into elasticsearch first. There are several different ways to do that, you can save the spreadsheet as CSV file and use logstash or you can use some specialized tools such as excelastic, but as far as I know none of the existing tools support re-reading the file and updating the index when the file is updated. So, you would need to write a script to do that part.